# In codeigniter, how to pass array to function parameter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, parameters

As title, I have a library function `$this->foo->bar()`. How can I pass `$upload_data` array to `$this->foo->bar()` param?

I have this in my controller

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
//$upload_data['file_name']
$this->foo->bar($upload_data);
```

Then I have this in my library

```
public function bar($arr){
    $config['source_name'] = //How can I use $arr['file_name'] in here
}
```

And I got this error
Message: Illegal string offset 'file_name'

```
var_dump($upload_data)

array (size=14)
 'file_name' => string '1358459309.JPG' (length=14)
 'file_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
 'file_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/foldering/assets/img/uploaded_photos/' (length=49)
 'full_path' => string 'C:/wamp/www/foldering/assets/img/uploaded_photos/1358459309.JPG'       (length=63)
 'raw_name' => string '1358459309' (length=10)
 'orig_name' => string '1358459309.JPG' (length=14)
 'client_name' => string '200X CNY1.JPG' (length=13)
 'file_ext' => string '.JPG' (length=4)
 'file_size' => float 30.87
 'is_image' => boolean true
 'image_width' => int 640
 'image_height' => int 480
 'image_type' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
 'image_size_str' => string 'width="640" height="480"' (length=24)
```

Comment: Can you please var_dump($upload_data) and let us know the result

Comment: @mallix added in question

Comment: If you get the same results inside the bar function, it should work.

Comment: @mallix   my mistake, the issue comes from another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, issue comes from another function

Comment: Is this an answer, I guess this needs to be a comment :)